# Loading MahApps from class library

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I working on an AutoCAD plugin (class library .dll) that references MahApps.Metro to pull in the various resource dictionaries. Everything looks fine in the designer but when I load the dll into AutoCAD it fails to find any references to MahApps.Metro? i.e. I get the following exception:

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.' Line number '18' and line position '18'. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MahApps.Metro, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

MahApps.Metro is set to copy local.

Here's the usercontrol xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BatchEngine.MainWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
              xmlns:MahAppsControls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
       Height="600" Width="850" MinWidth="850" DataContext="{Binding}" MinHeight="600">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Icons.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />

                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseDark.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
"Design data here"
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Any ideas what i'm missing

Comment: Managed to figure out what was wrong. AutoCAD requires the to be netloaded before interaction. Once loaded everything worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me it was because one of the dependencies:
**System.Windows.Interactivity.dll**
was not copied into the output folder. This dll is needed by the **MahApp.Metro.dll**.